# Gerar sequencia no R

Tags: r

minha logica esta falhando. Mas voceês poderiam me ajudar a criar um vetor de numeros no R com essa regra aqui?

```
Vetor=1,222,2,223,3,224,4,.......,221,442
```

Muitissimo obrigado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
rep(1:221, each = 2) + c(0, 221)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use o `rbind()` para intercalar as sequências.

```
x = rep(1:221)
y = (x + 221)

Vetor = c(rbind(x, y))

head(Vetor)
#[1]   1 222   2 223   3 224
```